# glGenTextures returns an undefined texture soon after glDeleteTextures

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am facing a strange issue where I end with an undefined but somehow valid texture. The mesh with this texture applied is black. The `glIsTexture(textureId)` method for this texture returns 1 (!) but the texture is clearly wrong. It has undefined size.

My iOS app creates several textures in short time intervals but always on the main thread. The described situation is unusual, difficult to reproduce and it occurs only in a particular scenario when:

- there is used `glDeleteTextures(1, &textureId)`, deleting a texture id = N
- in short time (~0.05s) there is used `glGenTextures(1, &textureId)` and the function returns a new texture with exactly the same id = N as the recently deleted one.

This looks to me like the OpenGL driver tried to create a new texture while an old one was not completely erased. Is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like the GL implementation is recycling the texture IDs. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Mesh with texture applied showing black indicates something is wrong with your texture setup and the shader is reading 0s for every texture sample.

Comment: @Rhythmic - recycling IDs is perfectly fine. The problem is that in very rare cases when the ID is recycled in a short time interval the new texture is black with no defined dimensions, however valid (glIsTexture(textureId) returns 1).

Comment: @James the texture setup is the same and 99.9% of textures are created correctly. The same setup fails in the scenario I described (short interval between delete and generate, operating on the same ID - both in the same thread).

Comment: @Greg: Well, it is not exactly clear what is going on in your application. Since you explicitely mention a main thread, are there other threads which are possibly interacting with the GL?  Also, I really don't know what eaxctly you expect. `glGenTextures` does _not_ create texture objects, it creates texture _names_ (the ID). The texture object is created when the ID is first bound to a texture unit. This of course will only create an empty texutre object wihout any image data.

Comment: The recycling of the texture IDs is perfectly fine. It doesn't matter if you get the same ID or a new one. you should do the texture setup in the same way as you will do for a new ID. 

The glGenTexture does not create a new Texture, it just generates the texture names or IDs. You can use your application generated unique texture IDs without calling the glGenTexture if you like. It should work as long as they are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was trivial - an unbound texture before calling `glTexImage2D` and setting up the texture.

I am using a group of wrapper methods over the OpenGL library. Their purpose is reducing the number of redundant state changes of the driver. One of this wrappers was preventing binding a texture with the same ID to a texture unit if it was previously flagged as bound.

In some cases, when the same ID was being recycled the wrapper method was still "remembering" the old texture ID and preventing binding is again.

Reassuming - in this case, there were completely no issues with `glDeleteTextures` followed by `glGenTextures`.